# SignalR ObjC returns "bad response code from server 403" when using WebSockets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iis, signalr

I am trying to set up an iOS client to use SignalR-ObjC with our web service.  When we use the long polling approach, everything seems to work but it has issues of its own with our production environment.  So I have been instructed to switch to using the Web Sockets approach. Based on code examples I've seen online I think it should be working with what I have but the service is returning an error through the `webSocket:didFailWithError:` method.  Here's the error:

```
Error Domain=org.lolrus.SocketRocket Code=2132 "received bad response code from server 403" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=received bad response code from server 403}
```

Here's my code for setting up the connection, found in our AppDelegate file:

```
<!-- language:objective c -->
-(void)initializePushNotificationsConnection
{
    // Connect to the hub on the service
    SRHubConnection* localHubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:kSignalRServiceUrl];
    SRHubProxy* notifications = (SRHubProxy*)[localHubConnection createHubProxy:@"notificationHub"];
    [notifications on:@"notificationSent" perform:self selector:@selector(addMessage:)];

    localHubConnection.started =  ^{

        NSString* userGuid = [OURAppSettings sharedSettings].loginModel.theUser.userGuid;
        if (!userGuid)
            userGuid = @"";

        NSString* connId = self.hubConnection.connectionId;
        if (!connId)
            connId = @"";

        NSDictionary* connectionDict = @{@"UserGuid": userGuid, @"Model": connId};
        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:connectionDict options:0 error:nil];
        NSURL* connectionRegistrationServiceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:kSignalRConnectionRegistrationUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:connectionRegistrationServiceUrl];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* connectionError)
         {
             if (connectionError)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
                 return;
             }
         }];

        return;
    };

    //Set the object to the local property to break the strong connection so the block can reference the object
    self.hubConnection = localHubConnection;
    SRWebSocketTransport *webSocket = [[SRWebSocketTransport alloc] init];
    [self.hubConnection start:webSocket];
}
```

I've tried multiple suggestions from Github and SO but none of them are solving this issue.  I suspect there is a problem with how the web service is setup but I'm not an IIS expert nor do I have easy access to the setup. I'm basically just guessing at solutions at this point, so if anyone has any thoughts or suggestions at all I'm open to hearing them.